# Select matching id arrays from give 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have 2 arrays  code written in php

```
Array
(
    [qty_ordered] => 12.0000
    [product_id] => 2080
    [product_name] => Watchadmin1
    [product_price] => 1010.0000
)
Array
(
    [qty_ordered] => 11.0000
    [product_id] => 2086
    [product_name] => WatchAdmin88
    [product_price] => 1010.0000
)
Array
(
    [qty_ordered] => 11.0000
    [product_id] => 2076
    [product_name] => admin3
    [product_price] => 1010.0000
)
```

and Second array collection is

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 2080
    [sku] => Watchadmin1
    [current_user_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 2081
    [sku] => Watchadmin8
    [current_user_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 2082
    [sku] => abc
    [current_user_id] => 1
)
```

I want to get all products from first array and store another new array when product_id of first array and entity_id of second array will same. ex `product_id=2080` and `entity_id=2080`
then this array will save another array .

can you guide me best code  ?

Comment: What language is this? Please add it as a tag.

Comment: am sorry . 
am using php

Comment: `$filter_product=[];

        foreach ($sellercollection as $allProduct){
            foreach ($bestsalecollection as $bestSale){
                if($allProduct->getEntityId()==$bestSale->getProductId()){
                    $filter_product[]=$bestSale;
                }
            }
        }`
this is not optimize code when 500 + products goes

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: get all products from array1 if product_id of array1 is match with entity_id in array2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk` and `in_array` to get the desired result

```
$res = [];
array_walk($arr1, function($v, $k) use (&$res,$arr2){
  in_array($v['product_id'], array_column($arr2, 'entity_id')) ? ($res[] = $v) : '';
});
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/stuj8)

Comment: Sir actually i have object not an array so get this error 

 `Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

Comment: @HaFizUmer you can convert object to array

Comment: i use this 
`$array =  (array) $yourObject;`

`Notice: Undefined index: product_id`

i think it make associate array

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch entity id and loop to get filtered products

```
$entityIds = $sellercollection->pluck("entity_id");
$filter_product = [];
foreach ($bestsalecollection as $bestSale) {
    if (in_array($bestSale->product_id,$entityIds)) {
        $filter_product[] = $bestSale;
    }
}
```

Purely in laravel

```
$entityIds = $sellercollection->pluck("entity_id");
$filter_product = $bestsalecollection->filter(function ($item) use ($entityIds) {
        return in_array(data_get($item, 'product_id'), $entityIds);
});
```

Here is [data_get](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-data-get) doc.

Here is [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck) doc.